# How do I parse newlines in TextField of pasted text?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm attempting to parse newlines from pasted text from the clipboard into a single-lined `TextField`. I'd like to replace the newlines with '\n' (or any other delimiter) in the text field and have it submit text with newlines ('\n' delimiter would suffice, as that's automatically parsed within my message box already).

Is there any method I could use to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set TextField.multiline = false
Otherwise you should replace /n and /r to other chars

```
import flash.desktop.Clipboard;
import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;
import flash.desktop.ClipboardTransferMode;

var newText = paste().replace("\n","").replace("\r",""); // get text from clipboard and replace newlines to ""
myTextField.text = newText; // place newText into the textfield.

private function paste():String
{
        if(Clipboard.generalClipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT))
        {
            return String(Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT));
        } 
        else 
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Not precisely what I was aiming for, but this definitely opens up many doors. Much appreciated :)